# How to change display of GET parameter from URL after applying Pretty Permalinks in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, permalinks

I have this "pretty permalink" for a page in my wordpress installation, and I have a page with an URL like this.

```
http://my-domain.com/bklorito/pedido-exitoso/
```

BUT, by the interaction with other plugin (WP-e-commerce), for the page to work, the URL loads like this:

```
http://my-domain.com/bklorito/pedido-exitoso/?sessionid=5801363279057
```

(It does operations with that $_GET variable)

But I was asked to change that to:

```
http://my-domain.com/bklorito/pedido-exitoso/5801363279057/
```

I have tried many things on .htaccess and through functions.php but I haven't succeeded.

I have already added:

```
function change_transaction_url() {
        if (isset($_GET['sessionid']) && !empty($_GET['sessionid'])) {
            $url_constructed = "pedido-exitoso/" . urlencode($_GET['sessionid'])."/";
            wp_redirect(home_url($url_constructed));
            exit();
        } else {
            $url_constructed = "pedido-exitoso/";
            wp_redirect(home_url($url_constructed));
            exit();
        }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'change_transaction_url');
```

And I get the URL format, but, I get a 404 Not Found error on it, since Wordpress doesn't know what he's really aiming at.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried RewriteRule in. htaccess?

Comment: After all my attempts, my htaccess is:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bklorito/
RewriteRule pedido-exitoso/(.+) pedido-exitoso/?sessionid=$1 [QSA,L,B]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bklorito/index.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^pedido-exitoso/(.+)$ pedido-exitoso/?sessionid=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^pedido-exitoso/(.*)$ index\.php?page=pedido-exitoso&sessionid=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule pedido-exitoso/(.+) pedido-exitoso/?sessionid=$2 [QSA,L,B]
</IfModule>
Put comments to my lines because they don't work.